# Как сделать загрузку изображений из Mysql быстрее?

Tags: php, mysql, изображения, blob

Храню картинки в блобах. Причем изображения проходят обработку и по размеру весят около 100 - 300 кб. Тем не менее вывод например 10 статей с картинкой на каждую занимает определенное время, картинки медленно появляются по очереди что видно невооруженным глазом. 
Есть ли наработанные способы более быстрого вывода?
пс [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/45966/) нашел неплохую идею, но так и не увидел программной реализации

Answer (score 7):

> Есть ли наработанные способы более быстрого вывода?

Есть, конечно.
Хранить картинки не в БД, а там, где положено - в файлах.

Comment: В данном случае я не рассматриваю этот вариант. Давайте оставим его на самый крайний случай.

Comment: @beatsspam Вот боюсь крайний случай уже настал. Вы же их небось еще и через скрипт выводите и браузер в итоге их не кеширует. что ведет и к избыточной нагрузке на сервер и замедлению открытия страницы у клиента. nginx картинку с диска между прочим отдает связывая дескриптор файла с сокетом, сама передача происходит на уровне ядра ОС. В случае с mysql сначала mysql разыскивает картинку у себя в блоках данных, ядро копирует из страниц ядра к в буфер mysql, потом из буфера обратно в память ядра, откуда они идут в ваш скрипт где происходит еще раз копирование туда-обратно

Comment: @beatsspam люде дело говорят: храните файлы на диске... если не хотите, чтобы люди могли к ним по прямому доступу обратиться - отдавайте через свой скрипт, а саму директорию с файлами защитите через htaccess: deny from all

Comment: @beatsspam по ссылке, Которую приводили в самом конце идея подана. хранить всё в базе и в кеше. Только придумать как обновить изображение в кеше, когда оно меняется в базе. Вероятно уже придуманы какие-то управляемые системы кеширования.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а как же клиен-серверные приложения (прикладное ПО)?

Comment: @I_CaR точно так же